# Android ANR/Crash on 4.4 version

Tags: android

All,

I am facing a ANR/Crash on Android 4.4 devices. Below are the mention log which I received from device. Still I an not able to debug/relate this issue. Could someone please help me to trace and fixed this issue.

> at android.view.GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList(Native Method) at
>   android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawDisplayList(GLES20Canvas.java:420) at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.drawDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1661)
>   at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1484)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2685) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2551) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2157) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1239) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6396)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613) at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583) at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please check and help me to fixing this.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: I recently faced a crash with the same stack trace on Samsung GT-N7108. How did you solve your problem? Somebody on SO suggested disabling [hardware acceleration.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) Now I'm trying to find the suggestion

Comment: The suggestion I talked about in the previous comment. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13822045/1065835

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev If you can get the crash to be reproduced again and again, can you show the relevant code? Just looking at the logs and no code is sometimes hard to provide any specific inputs

Comment: @AADTechnical Basically I found this crash when we try to open the menu option on screen. Still I can't able to reproduce it. But my AppSee get this error always. Not sure but it happens only on APPSEE

Comment: what's the "Caused By" message?

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable **hardware acceleration** for the **scrollview at runtime**.

```
View scroll = layout.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
scroll.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I found this for more detailed explanation it may helps you check once

[WebView in ScrollView: "View too large to fit into drawing cache" - how to rework layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471194/webview-in-scrollview-view-too-large-to-fit-into-drawing-cache-how-to-rewor?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I'd like a more detailed answer. If you edit yours, I might accept it

Comment: @UmaAchanta I dant have uses Scroll view in my fragment. Not sure this will work for me. Anyway thanks :)